# Linking BootsFaces BrandImg

Tags: css, image, jsf, menu, bootsfaces

I'm new to JSF and can't figure out how to add the link for my image in my Navbar for Bootsfaces.

```
<b:container>
        <b:navBar brandImg="WHAT_DO_I_PUT_HERE?"
                  id="navbar-main"
                  inverse="false" 
                  sticky="true"
```

I've looked everywhere to try and figure out how to link the image inside of BrandImg and there isn't any information that I can find. I have my logo.png file stored in my resources -> images folder.

Answer (score 1):

The `brandImg` is simply the URL of the image to display. It may be relative or absolute.

Currently, there's no support for images stored in the resources folder. Of course, you can always use an URL like "#{request.contextPath}/resources/images/logo.png".